# Proving some properties of unimodular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A matrix $U\in \mathbb{Z}^{n\times n}$ is unimodular if it has a multiplicative inverse $\mathbb{Z}^{n\times n}$, i. e. there is a matrix $V\in \mathbb{Z}^{n\times n}$ such that $VU=UV=I$.

$(1)$ If $U$ is unimodular, so is $U^{-1}$.

I think I can just choose $V^{-1}$ as the multiplicative Inverse: $V^{-1}U^{-1}=U^{-1}V^{-1}=E$ since $V^{-1}U^{-1}=(UV)^{-1}=E$ and likewise $U^{-1}V^{-1}=(VU)^{-1}=E$.

$(2)$ If $U$ and $V$ are unimodular, so is $UV$

There exists $K,W\in \mathbb{Z}^{n\times n}$ such that $KU=UK=E$ and $WV=VW=E$. For $UV$, I think you can choose $WK$:$$WKUV=UVWK=E$$

$(3)$ $U$ is unimodular iff $\det(U)=\pm 1$

$\Rightarrow$ Let $U$ be unimodular, then $\det(U)=\det(V^{-1})=\frac{1}{\det{V}}\in \mathbb{Z}$ since all entries of $U$ are integer. For $\frac{1}{\det{V}}$ to be integer, we have to choose $\pm 1$.

$\Leftarrow$ Let $\det(U)=\pm 1$, how can I show that $U$ is unimodular?

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Matrix_is_Invertible_iff_Determinant_has_Multiplicative_Inverse

Comment: Look up the adjugate matrix

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Is $(1)$ and $(2)$ correct, are you referring to the part missing in$(3)$?

Comment: (1),(2) are correct. The comments address your question: the missing implication in (3).